# Invalid audio channel count for single channel audio file

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I have a wav audio file, which i have converted to single channel and further onto FLAC audio form.

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/tcssig/Downloads/sample.wav")

sound.channels 
1

## request.json

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "languageCode": "fi-FI"
  },
  "audio": {
     "uri":"gs://g_stt/fin11.flac"
  }
}
```

### API Request

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('key', '****************************'),
)

data = open('/Users/tcssig/Documents/request.json', 'rb').read()
response = requests.post('https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
```

Using the google speech to text api for generating a transcript, it gives me the error response :

```
{'error': {'code': 400,
  'message': 'Invalid audio channel count',
  'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}}
```

Because the API supports Mono channel and not the stereo channel, i can not understand why is this happening for a single audio channel file in FLAC format.

Comment: Looks like the audio file is not single channel. Share the file if you unable to check yourself.

Comment: yes thats the reason, but i checked the file in python using sound.channels command and it shows single channel. Later i used gui based tool to convert it into a FLAC Mono channel file and it went through Correctly.